# PyGI: Create pixbuf from 0

Tags: python, pygtk, pygobject

I want to do a image of a cable (line) between two points. I thought on doing the cable with the distance between the two points and then rotating the image the number of degrees that have the two points between.

But I don't know how to create a image from nothing. I mean, doing a image of 5px wide and "x" lenght, and then rotate it "y" degrees.

Also if I could select the color, that would be nice.

Sorry for my bad English and thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to create a svg e.g. using the svgwrite module and load it with a PixbufLoader. The rotation can be done by calculating the corresponding coordinates or using a svg transformation.

```
import svgwrite
from gi.repository import GdkPixbuf

drawing = svgwrite.Drawing(size=('100px', '100px'))
line = drawing.line(start=(50, 0), end=(50, 100), stroke='blue')
drawing.add(line)
encoded = drawing.tostring().encode()

loader = GdkPixbuf.PixbufLoader()
loader.write(encoded)
loader.close()
pixbuf = loader.get_pixbuf()
```